# Weight of TextField not reflecting in it's label (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android, responsive, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create a responsive layout using 'weights'. For large screen, the weights seem to work fine for TextFields, but for smaller screen, the hint text of TextField overlaps with the underbar. The only reason I can think for this is that the weight provided is working fine for the TextField but it's not causing the hint text to decrease it's size for smaller devices.

Below are the screenshots:

[image: TextFields in large device]

[image: TextFields in small device]

This is a code snippet I'm using:

```
     Column(
            Modifier
                .padding(end = 0.dp, top = 220.dp)
                .align(TopCenter)) {
            val query = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            TextField(
                value = query.value,
                onValueChange = { newValue -> query.value = newValue },
                label = {
                    Text(
                        "Name as on Pan Card",
                        color = colorResource(id = R.color.fade_green),
                    )
                },
                textStyle = TextStyle(
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.fade_green),
                    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.poppins_regular)),
                    fontSize = with(LocalDensity.current){
                            dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._11ssp).toSp()},
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(
                        CenterHorizontally
                    )
                    .weight(0.25f),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(

                    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green),
                    focusedIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green)
                )
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))

            TextField(
                value = query.value,
                onValueChange = { newValue -> query.value = newValue },
                label = { Text("Email", color = colorResource(id = R.color.fade_green)) },
                textStyle = TextStyle(
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.fade_green),
                    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.poppins_regular)),
                    fontSize = with(LocalDensity.current){
                        dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._11ssp).toSp()},
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(
                        CenterHorizontally
                    )
                    .weight(0.25f),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(

                    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green),
                    focusedIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green)
                )
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))

            TextField(
                value = query.value,
                onValueChange = { newValue -> query.value = newValue },
                label = { Text("Mobile Number", color = colorResource(id = R.color.fade_green)) },
                textStyle = TextStyle(
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                    color = colorResource(id = R.color.fade_green),
                    fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.poppins_regular)),
                    fontSize = with(LocalDensity.current){
                        dimensionResource(id = R.dimen._11ssp).toSp()},
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(
                        CenterHorizontally
                    )
                    .weight(0.25f),
                colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(

                    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                    unfocusedIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green),
                    focusedIndicatorColor = colorResource(id = R.color.bright_green)
                )
        )
```

How do I fix this? Or what other way can I use to create a responsive layout?

Comment: This is may because the screen can't fit all the components, so it cuts their size. Try making the column scrollable.

Comment: @ameencarpenter, shouldn't the TextField and the Text used with label within it work together in an integrated way?

Comment: It depends on the implementation. But you should always make your layout responsive when there's not enough space to fit the all components on the screen such as in landscape mode. Adding the scrollable modifier will fix your problem.